# How spoof referrer using curl

Tags: curl

I am using curl code below to spoof referrer , it works fine but there is error on every page - `Curl error:`

```
$url = somesite.com
function doMagic($url)
{
  $curl = curl_init();

  $header[0] = "Accept: text/xml,application/xml,application/xhtml+xml,";
  $header[0] .= "text/html;q=0.9,text/plain;q=0.8,image/png,*/*;q=0.5";
  $header[] = "Cache-Control: max-age=0";
  $header[] = "Connection: keep-alive";
  $header[] = "Keep-Alive: 300";
  $header[] = "Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7";
  $header[] = "Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5";
  $header[] = "Pragma: ";

  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:7.0.1) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/7.0.12011-10-16 20:23:00");
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_REFERER, "http://www.facebook.com");
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_ENCODING, "gzip,deflate");
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, true);
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION,true);

  $html = curl_exec($curl);
  echo 'Curl error: '. curl_error($curl);
  curl_close($curl);

  return $html;
}

$text = doMagic($url);
print("$text");
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Which curl error? could you be more specific ?

Comment: above code spoof referrer OK but there is text on page "Curl error:" nothing else,

Comment: Because you output "Curl error:" in your code all the time?

Comment: it show target site also with "Curl error:" text on page

Comment: can i hide error like in php with something like showerror = off/hide

Comment: please give me another working curl code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove this line from your code

```
echo 'Curl error: '. curl_error($curl);
```